# How can I alter the region lock on a Canon printer?

Tags: printer, inkjet-printer, canon-pixma

I have a Canon Pixma MP560 and some new, genuine cartridges from Best Buy.

When I install them, the ink cartridge lights light up, as if the printer recognised them, but when I close the printer lid, the printer just says:

> Error U140: the following cartridges are not recognised [picture of all of the cartridges]

**Update:** Apparently this is due to Canon region-locking their printers and cartridges. How can I alter the region on a Canon printer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pixus MP990 Rejecting US Ink Cartridges](http://superuser.com/questions/218725/pixus-mp990-rejecting-us-ink-cartridges)

Answer (score 3):

Here's the response from Canon:

> Thank you for contacting Canon product support.  We value you as a
>   Canon customer and appreciate the opportunity to assist you.  I am
>   sorry that your PIXMA MP560 is not recognizing the CLI-221 and PGI-220
>   ink tanks you purchased.
>
> The reason that the printer is not recognizing these ink tanks is
>   because these were purchased here in the United States and your PIXMA
>   MP560 was from the United Kingdom.  The ink must be purchased from the
>   Canon division where you purchased the printer.  Unfortunately, this
>   means that the ink from the United States would not work in your UK
>   PIXMA MP560.  It would need to come from a United Kingdom dealer.
>
> I am sorry for any inconvenience this causes.  Please let us know if
>   we can be of further assistance with your PIXMA MP560.

**TLDR** Canon **region locks** its print cartridges.

Update: It is possible to alter the region of cartridges, notably using a "redsetter" device, which also resets ink levels (as electronically recorded).